# XmlReader and NodeTypes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file I need to read from to get some text values. I am having trouble with the reader.NodeType = XMLNodeType.Text and understanding what constitutes a node to be of NodeType.Text.

My XML reader is only picking up NodeType = Element and ignoring any text in between the node declarations.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myxmlfile>
  <ActivitiesHelp>
  <helptext>Some text goes here I need to read.</helptext>
  </ActivitiesHelp>
</myxmlfile>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
elementName = formName.Replace(" ", "");
while (reader.Read())
{
    // when we find an element node, we remember its name  
    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == elementName))
    {
        reader.Read();
        //if the next node = 'helptext' then get that text data
        if (reader.Name == "helptext")
        {
            // for text nodes...get the text values
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
            {
                formMessage = reader.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The if statement for `Nodetype == XmlNodeType.Text` never hits true.

What am I doing wrong, and how do you specify a nodetype of Text in XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need to do this:

```
if (reader.Name == "helptext")
        {
            reader.Read();
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
            {
                formMessage = reader.Value;
            }
        }
```

i.e. the helptext node is an Element, the text it's childnode and is of type TextNode

Comment: Thanks Ben. I continued to play with it and debug and actually just found that out about 2mins after you posted! Hehe, all I needed was one more reader.Read();