# C# WinForm, how to write current text in a text box to a new file

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

So I'm working on this application that reads an XML file and writes it to a textbox and so far so good.

However I would like to have a button that when clicked opens a "save as" dialog window, lets the user create a new .txt file and then reads the content of the textbox and saves it.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("filePath", textBoxPath.Text);` ?

Comment: sounds like a possible `duplicate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325766/xmlreader-and-nodetypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a "Save file" dialog with `SaveFileDialog` :

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    // save to saveFileDialog.FileName
```

To write the text in your `TextBox` :

`File.WriteAllText( saveFileDialog.FileName, textbox.Text );`